# Switching from shared host to vps and getting "Illegal characters in path"

Tags: c#, asp.net, shared-hosting, vps, illegal-characters

Okay, I'm ripping my hair out here. I took over some code from a previous developer and I it does a lot and goes very deep to say the least. Anyway I have been fighting this issue for a few days and cannot figure it out.

I have copied the exact code from the shared webhost (aspwebhosting) that runs fine and I copied it to our vps and now I get this error thrown and I cannot figure out where it is coming from or what the problem is. Please someone help me.

```
   System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_PhysicalPath()
   at WebsitePanel.IIsModules.SecureFolders.context_OnEnter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Clearly some your custom module `WebsitePanel.IIsModules.SecureFolders` does something that involve invalid path... I'm afraid nothing more can be said without more data.

Comment: What is the full path that throws that ?